# How do I get Captcha to reappear in my registration form if an error was detected after submission?

Tags: 7, captcha

I'm using Drupal 7 and have added an image Captcha as part of the registration process. The Captcha works just fine but if the form is submitted with an error, it no longer appears with the rest of the form when the registration page reloads. How do I make sure it always reappears? Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched the module's issue queue?  It should normally re-appear if the user inputs the wrong value.

Comment: @PatrickKenny it's in module settings, you can set it to appear always, once per form or once per session. It defaulted to first one, but as far as I remember there was an issue to change default. Too bad I don't have it installed to test and make screenshots

Comment: I can't believe the answer was that simple. I guess I misunderstood what the default option under Persistence meant. Thanks.

Comment: @jsalita so you say it really was a good enough answer? Guess I will put it as one, then. Feel free to edit it with exact path and screenshot for future users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in module settings. Under Persistence , you can set CAPTCHA to appear:

- always,
- once per form,
- once per session.

It used to default to always, but as far as I remember there was an issue to change default. Probably now it defaults to once per form or once per session. It should be enough to manually change it to always.